# Module not found 'express' when deploying to azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure, express, deployment, continuous-integration

I have a node server.js file which i can run just fine locally, and it looks like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const compression = require('compression')
const path = require('path')
const { renderPage } = require('vite-plugin-ssr/server')

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..')
const clientPath = path.join(root, 'client')

async function startServer() {
  const app = express()

  app.use(compression())

  if (isProduction) {
    const sirv = require('sirv')
    app.use(sirv(clientPath))
  } else {
    const vite = require('vite')
    const viteDevMiddleware = (
      await vite.createServer({
        root,
        server: { middlewareMode: true },
      })
    ).middlewares
    app.use(viteDevMiddleware)
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  app.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
    const pageContextInit = {
      urlOriginal: req.originalUrl,
    }
    const pageContext = await renderPage(pageContextInit)
    const { httpResponse } = pageContext
    if (!httpResponse) return next()
    const {
      body, statusCode, contentType, earlyHints,
    } = httpResponse
    if (res.writeEarlyHints) res.writeEarlyHints({ link: earlyHints.map((e) => e.earlyHintLink) })
    res.status(statusCode).type(contentType).send(body)
  })

  const port = process.env.PORT || 5173
  app.listen(port)
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`)
}

startServer()
```

I can also serve it from my dist folder after running npm run build without any issues. But as soon as i deploy it to my app service in azure and try to run it there i get the error. Here is my app service startup command:

```
pm2 start js/server.js --no-daemon
```

My pipeline looks like this:

```
name: Azure dev deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main
env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: {name}
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: './dist'
  NODE_VERSION: '16.x'                

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: node:16
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: set script to remove husky in CI
        run: npm set-script prepare ''
      - name: Dependency installation
        run: npm ci
      - name: linter
        run: npm run lint
      - name: build
        env:
          DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN: true
        run: npm run build --if-present
      - name: tests
        env:
          DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN: true
        run: npm test
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure WebApp'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with: 
          app-name: ${{ appName }}
          publish-profile: ${{ publishProfile }}
```

Should node_modules and/or package.json be included in my deployment package to my app service? I'm a bit lost here and trying to speculate as to why I'm getting this error and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the express.js is included in the node modules in your github repository where you're running the github action workflow:-

**My github repository with Express.js app:-**

[image]

**My package.json:-**

```json
{
  "name": "myexpressapp7",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "pm2": "^5.3.0"
  }
}
```

**node modules folder contains express package:-**

[image]

**My github workflow:-**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - valleywebapp984

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'valleywebapp984'
          slot-name: 'production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_2eccd9239cc34b3990c26fadf7c6ae60 }}
          package: .
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

In order to run the pm2 server, Refer my SO thread answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76499294/cant-run-express-app-on-azure-app-service-with-pm2-cli-not-found/76505481#76505481)

Add this as a start up command in the Web app, reload your web app and check the Log stream like below:-

Start up command:-

```bash
pm2 start  ./bin/www
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!
I double checked my package.json and node_modules folder, express exists in both. My github actions deployment goes green and seems to be fine. I am also able to run the app with pm2 but it crashes after a while with the "Cannot find module" error. Currently I deploy my application to the /home/site/wwwroot directory, but I'm not sure if that could be an issue. Earlier iteration of my application was client-side rendered, and the site ran fine from the wwwroot, but since I've switched to server-side rendering, maybe server code should not be put there?

Comment: In order to add node modules that includes express.js make sure you add the below setting SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to false this will make sure that the node modules are included in the deployment package. Also try to run npm ci command to install all the dependencies from package.lock.json file, Validate your package.lock.json file and make sure it includes the required express package. Also, /home/site/wwwroot seems to be the correct directory for your application deployment. After deployment, Visit Advanced tools > Kudu > And check the location of your deployed files?

Comment: Added SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT and set it to false, I ran npm run ci and i could verify that express exists in the package-lock.json as well as package.json and in node_modules. When i go to Kudu i can also verify that my files are correctly in the /home/site/wwwroot 
However, I can't find any package.json or package-lock.json in my wwwroot or anywhere else in kudu, same for node_modules. But from my understanding it should not matter since the dependency installation step in my pipeline passes without any issue.

Comment: I just realised that if i ssh into /home/site/wwwroot and run npm i express the error disappears. Should i deploy package.json and node_modules to /home/site/wwwroot ? Is that bad?

Comment: No, It's not bad, That is fine

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what my terminal spits out when I `az webapp log tail`